# Krajee bootstrap file input, show image from database not working with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I'm using Krajee file input and I need to load an image from database to it
I tried this:

myController:

```
def DisplayImage() {   
   def aluno = Aluno.get(params.id)
   response.outputStream << aluno.foto
   response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

and this is the input field and script:

```
<input id="input-2" name="foto" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="false"
       data-show-caption="true"/>
<script>
    $(".file").fileinput({
        showUpload: false,
        initialPreview: [
            '<g:if test="${aluno?.foto?.length > 0}"> <img src="${createLink(controller: 'myController', action: 'DisplayImage', params: ['id': object?.id])}"/> </g:if>'
        ]
    });
</script>
```

it works when I load the page, but no if I load the page through ajax

What am I missing?

Obs: the script is inside the page that I load through ajax.

Thanks!

Comment: at the end of your <script> tag try to add alert('hello'); and verify the hello message appear, if not, it will mean your script is not executed. If it's ok maybe then try to include all the content of your tag script in $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Comment: tried it, the alert is shown when I load my page through  ajax

Comment: Can you show your js code that write/append the loaded ajax page in your html page ?

Comment: I solved the problem, for some reason when I put my script and css imports right above my input file it worked.. thanks